# Would it be possible to improve camera_fit_coords in my zoom method with a generator?

Tags: python, camera

I'm trying to improve my zoom_to method for moving the camera towards an object in the scene:

```
def zoom_to(scene, camera, object):

    co_list = []
    for point_co in [point[:] for point in object.bound_box]:
        for co in point_co:
            co_list.append(co)

    loc_new_for_cam, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(scene, co_list)

    camera.location = loc_new_for_cam
```

However I'm not quite understanding how camera_fit_coords works and I'm wondering if a python generator would improve the code by not having the double for-cycle build a useless list.

I tried with:

```
def gen_co_list(obj):
    for point_co in [point[:] for point in obj.bound_box]:
        for co in point_co:
            yield co

def zoom_to_g(scene, camera, obj):
    loc_new_for_cam, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(scene, gen_co_list(obj))
    camera.location = loc_new_for_cam
```

But I get:

> ValueError: Object.camera_fit_coords(): error with argument 2, "coordinates" -  sequence expected at dimension 1, not 'generator'

Also, if there is a way of avoiding foo completely, this could be a one-liner even. It might not be as clear, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: found the true improvement thanks to @batFINGER**

After using the tip from @batFINGER and some other minor modification (I was initially editing gen_co_list...), the method can become a still comprehensible one-liner:

```
 def zoom_to_g5(scene, camera, object):
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    camera.location, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, [co for corner in object.bound_box for co in corner])
```

I wanted a faster method, so I'm using list comprehension instead of a generator. There shouldn't be a memory problem since there are only ever 8 corners in the bounding box.

The method is ~25% faster, clocking in at:

```
>>>print(min(timeit.Timer('cam.location=0.0,0.0,7.0; zoom_to_g5(scn, cam, obj)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.007111115999578033
```

**OLD**

It seems it was a mistake in my comprehension of generators, and the code should have been:

```
def gen_co_list(object):
    for point_co in [point[:] for point in object.bound_box]:
        for co in point_co:
            yield co

def zoom_to_g(scene, camera, object):
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    loc_new_for_cam, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, [co for co in gen_co_list(object)])
    camera.location = loc_new_for_cam
```

That said, trying to time the code yields different results than what I expected:

```
setup = """
import bpy
scn = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
def zoom_to(scene, camera, object):
    co_list = []
    for point_co in [point[:] for point in object.bound_box]:
        for co in point_co:
            co_list.append(co)
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    loc_new_for_cam, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, co_list)
    camera.location = loc_new_for_cam
   
def gen_co_list(object):
    for point_co in [point[:] for point in object.bound_box]:
        for co in point_co:
            yield co

def zoom_to_g(scene, camera, object):
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    loc_new_for_cam, foo = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, [co for co in gen_co_list(object)])
    camera.location = loc_new_for_cam
"""

>>>print(min(timeit.Timer('cam.location=0.0,0.0,7.0; zoom_to(scn, cam, obj)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.009414574999937031
>>>print(min(timeit.Timer('cam.location=0.0,0.0,7.0; zoom_to_g(scn, cam, obj)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.00963822900030209
```

run on blender's classic cube.

I will therefore stick with the first zoom_to version, even though I thought the contrary would happen.

Comment: Be tempted to return a generator  `return (axis for p in C.object.bound_box for axis in p)` and avoid  the list copy `point[:]`

Comment: That's what I was looking for! After 3 more iterations of code improvement I have the better method, and it is ~25% faster than the original one!